# callback function with universal argument handling

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a JS function which handles its arguments independedently from where it is called.
AFAIK the arguments differ, depending where the function is called.

**Example 1**

A commom usage is to register the function in HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="myFunc(this);">
```

The element will then be passed on to the function:

```
function myfunc(element) {
    alert(element.value);
}
```

**Example 2**

Another, appoach is to register it dynamically, when the document is finished loading. Something along those lines:

```
// init() gets called when document is ready
function init() {
    document.getElementById('text2').addEventListener('keyup', myFunc2);
}
```

*Now the function will receive an Event-Object instead of an Element-Object.*
I need to change the functions code to access the information.

```
function myFunc2(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    alert(element.value);
}
```

**Example 3**

One way to solve this problem would be to completely ingnore arguments and always gather all information inside the function, like this:

```
function myFunc3(event) {
    var element = document.getElementById('text3');
    alert(element.value);
}
```

The ugly thing about this solution is, that the GUI will be thigtly coupled to the logic.

**Example 4?**

One solution I can think of would be to change *Solution 1* and pack the `this` into an Event-Object? I have not tried this yet and I'm not sure how to do this most elegantly.

Ps: No JQuery "allowed"

Comment: Forget about solution 1 because binding events directly in the HTML code is a bad practice and a common beginner way of doing things. Solution 3 is clumsy and will make a DOM call (`element = document.getElementById('text3')`) on every key press, which can be very resource consuming. Solution 2 looks good, you get all the info you need passed along with the event. You get your element with `element = event.target`, you did it yourself. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You can pass the event object from an inline handler too: `onclick="myFunc(event);"`. Though I agree with Jeremy, inline handlers are bad practice.

Comment: This is actually the solution I'm looking for `onclick="myFunc(event);"`. The reason why I'm asking is purely educational (I'm teaching this stuff to beginners). And they somethimes need to first learn **Example 1** even though it is concidered bad. So I was looking for a smooth transition from **Example 1** to **Example 2**. Can somebody make this as an answer? Then I can accept it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Looks like Icepickle has answered according to your requirements. Btw. Please don't teach your students "JSON objects", and specifically don't teach 'em "JSON arrays".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one can be rewritten like this (note that it's preferred not to mix your markup with event handlers, however if you really want it to, then it can be written like this)

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="myFunc(event);">
```

and the second one will take the input from the events `target` property.

```js
function myFunc(e) {
  let element = e.target;
  console.log( 'event comming from ' + element.id );
  console.log( 'current value is ' + element.value );
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let el = document.querySelector('#text2');
  el.addEventListener('keyup', myFunc);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeyup="myFunc(event);">
<input type="text" id="text2">
```

Comment: The first one should not be written at all.

Comment: @JeremyThille I would agree that it doesn't fit, however if it has to be written, then it can be written like this to support uniform parameter values

Comment: Just noticed this too. Would only `event` work in most browsers?

Comment: @Teemu You are right, changed it, was testing it on Vivaldi ;)

Comment: Can somebody explain simplified why `onkeyup="myFunc(event);"` should not be used (as stated here in the comments)? I mean specifically in comparison to `onkeyup="myFunc(this);"`. I think it is clear that we don't want to couple GUI and Logic, but is there any specific reason not to use `event`?

Comment: @BorisDäppen No, it's mainly about the coupling GUI and logic  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This covers both cases:

```
function foo(e) {
    let element = e.target || e;
}
```

Comment: very neat and elegant but kind of a hack :-) I think it makes more sence to replace `this` with `event`: `onclick="myFunc(event);"`

Comment: If you want to support older JavaScript styles (`onkeypress="..."` and so on) better get used to kinda hacks. :)

Comment: Replacing `this` with `event` won't do anything: you're just renaming things, the underlying objects won't change.

Comment: `this` passes an Element-Object, `event` passes an Event-Object (containing the Element-Object). Thus the handling on the receiving part is slightly different (`element.value` vs `event.target.value`). At least this is what others suggestet here and it seems to work as intended.

Comment: Didn't know that, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your function check the instance/type of the argument(s) and delegate the logic to other functions.

```
function myGeneralFunction(arg) {
  if(arg instanceof Event) {
    return handerForEvents(arg);
  }
  return otherHandler(arg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it makes more sence to replace `this` with `event`: `onclick="myFunc(event);"`